# Joomla: Include external page without iframe to apply own CSS?

Tags: css, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to load an external page into a module position, but apply the CSS definitions of my own template to the remotely loaded content.
I tried Joomla's wrapper module, but that loads the content into an iframe, which prevents applying my own templates CSS definitions, due to same domain principle...

Is there a way to load the content without surrounding iFrame?
E.g. using an Ajax request to load the HTML code from the remote site and then seamlessly wrapping it into the modules position?

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Sascha.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not posible. The idea of the @include directive in all of it's variations (iframes, @include, $.get, etc...) is to show external content from your website that you just can't style or edit.

Sory man, all I can tell you... good luck!